# Adobe AIR StageVide with camera NetStream

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am trying attach the flash.media.Camera to a NetStream object which would then be attached to StageVideo object.

I am told this is the only way to make StageVideo work on Android, but i just cannot make it work.

I am currently doing this and i can't figure out what is the problem:

1.Adding the stage video availability listener.

```
stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, availabilityChanged);
```

2.

```
private function availabilityChanged(event:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void {

    vidLocal = stage.stageVideos[0];

    rtmpNow = "rtmp://left";
    nc=new NetConnection();
    setCam();
    setVideo();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,checkCon);
    nc.connect(rtmpNow);

}
```

3.

```
private function checkCon(e:NetStatusEvent):void
{

    good = e.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success";
    if (good)
    {
        trace("good good");
        nsOut = new NetStream(nc);
        nsOut.attachCamera(cam);
        nsOut.publish("left","live");
        nsOut.play("left");
        vidLocal.attachNetStream(nsOut);
    }
}
private function setCam()
{
    cam = Camera.getCamera();
    cam.setKeyFrameInterval(9);
    cam.setMode(640,400,30);
    cam.setQuality(0,95);
}


private function setVideo()
{
    vidLocal.viewPort = new Rectangle(cam.width,cam.height);
    vidLocal.attachCamera(cam);
}
```

My biggest problem is that i don't know what is the string for the NetConnection?